# AT Commands in C#

Tags: c#, serial-port, at-command

I am totally unaware of how to use AT commands in c#, i have read a few articles on AT Commands, but I am unable to implement it in my c# code. This **Code** shows **No Error** but still it is not sending a Text Message.

```
string number="00923*******";
string message="Hello World!";
SerialPort _serialPort = new SerialPort("COM6",9600);
_serialPort.Open();
Thread.Sleep(1000);
_serialPort.Write("AT+CMGF=1\r");
_serialPort.Write("AT+CMGF=\"" + number + "\"\r\n")

Thread.Sleep(1000);
_serialPort.Write(message + "\x1A");
Thread.Sleep(1000);
_serialPort.Close();
```

Is there something i am doing wrong ?

Any Help or Suggestions regarding This Query will be Appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: CMGF is for SMS services, I would suggest an existing library like http://www.scampers.org/steve/sms/libraries.htm

Comment: bro, actually i am trying to send a short message, so i think i should stick to CMGF

Comment: The library will do that, without arbitrary hit-and-hope delays whilst monitoring the output from the device for errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AT commands only cause problems in C# because of string escape sequences. Send the commands using ASCII codes. I suppose you are trying to send an SMS. So try as:

```
string CellNumber ="00923*******";
string SMSMessage="Hello World!";

if (serialPort.IsOpen)
{
     this.serialPort.WriteLine(@"AT" + (char)(13));
     Thread.Sleep(200);
     this.serialPort.WriteLine("AT+CMGF=1" + (char)(13));
     Thread.Sleep(200);
     this.serialPort.WriteLine(@"AT+CMGS=""" + CellNumber + @"""" + (char)(13));
     Thread.Sleep(200);
     this.serialPort.WriteLine(SMSMessage + (char)(26));
     serialPort.Close();
     return true;
}
```

Comment: bro Would you please explain the use of `(char)(13)` and `(char)(26)` and the `@""""`

Comment: does it work?? (char)(any value) converts to equivalent ASCII .. see ASCII tables for further info. @"""" is actually closing the inverted commas inside an inverted comma. since WriteLine method demands a string and so we have to give a string inside a string to pass it to serial port

Comment: No Not Tested yet, Currently I am Unable to test the sample code you provided, soon I'll Test the Corrections You've made to my code, Thanks alot bro! :)